# Remove Dimensions for WP image URLs for custom sizes

Tags: wordpress, image, url, dimensions

I was thinking of something interesting that I want to apply at my Wordpress installation but I can't figure it out how to do it. So, here's that task:

1. I have set some custom image sizes in functions.php, as following:
       
       `add_image_size( 'fullcustomsize', 1170, 600, true );
       add_image_size( 'mediumcustomsize', 410, 270, true );
       add_image_size( 'smallcustomsize', 370, 370, true );`
2. This results in the following generated URLs of the image:

   ```
   original - image.jpg
   fullcustomsize - image-1170x600.jpg
   mediumcustomsize - image-410x270.jpg
   smallcustomsize - image-370x370.jpg
   ```
3. NOW, the tricky part. I want to make it this way:

   ```
   original - image-original.jpg
   fullcustomsize - image-1170x600.jpg
   mediumcustomsize - image.jpg
   smallcustomsize - image-370x370.jpg
   ```

Does somebody know a way to force Wordpress do this kind of URL generation? The thing is that I want to insert custom sized images in my posts but I do not want the dimensions in the URL of each image.

Thanks for the ideas in advance!!!

Comment: Just curious...What would be the use case / purpose for doing something like this?

Comment: There are two ways to insert custom sized images in my post without the dimensions in the URL. The first one is with a trick like the above. The second one is to resize each image before being uploaded which is time consuming when speaking of huge volumes.

Comment: I think the naming conventions are fairly deep-rooted in WP core, though there might be something out there (`mod_rewrite` perhaps?) that might help. This might be overkill though, and what @mevius said is something to think about - it may not be needed.